# Как сделать имя в чате в Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter, чат

я делаю мессенджер на tkinter. Пытаюсь релизовать чтобы пользователь вводил ник и текст а потом отображалось как {name} - 'text',  что у меня не правильно?
текст ошибки:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

код указан снизу

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1920x1080')

background = Label(root, bg='#cfd5db', text='SPECTAPS MESSENGER').pack(fill='both', anchor=SW)
input_user = StringVar()
input_field = Entry(root, text=input_user, bg='lightblue')
input_field.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=E)

input_name1 = StringVar()
input_name2 = Entry(root, text=input_name1, bg='#09C')
input_name2.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)
global get_name
def name(event):
    get_name = input_name2.get()
    return 'break'

def enter_pressed(event):
    input_get = input_field.get()
    label = Label(frame, text=input_get, bg='#F5F5F5')
    input_user.set('')
    label.pack(anchor=W)
    return 'break'



frame = Text(root, width=57, height=47, bg='#F5F5F5')
frame.pack_propagate(False)
input_field.bind('<Return>', (name, enter_pressed))
frame.pack(anchor=E, side=RIGHT)
frame.config(state=DISABLED)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вторым параметром `bind` метода должна передаваться функция (метод), а вы передаете кортеж (`tuple`), вот и ругается, что `tuple` не вызываемый объект (его нельзя вызывать как функцию).

В вашем случае нужно просто объединить две функции в одну, в этой функции получаете и имя пользователя из текстового поля, и выводимый текст, и добавляете их во фрейм:

```
...


def enter_pressed(event):
    name = input_name2.get()
    # Метка синего цвета с именем пользователя + двоеточие
    label = Label(frame, text=name + ":", fg='#0000FF', bg='#F5F5F5')  
    label.pack(anchor=W)

    input_get = input_field.get()
    label = Label(frame, text=input_get, bg='#F5F5F5')
    label.pack(anchor=W)

    input_user.set('')


frame = Text(root, width=57, height=47, bg='#F5F5F5')
frame.pack_propagate(False)
input_field.bind('<Return>', enter_pressed)
frame.pack(anchor=E, side=RIGHT)
frame.config(state=DISABLED)
root.mainloop()
```

Вообще, для добавления текста в текстовое поле лучше использовать метод `insert`, а не использовать текстовое поле как фрейм для меток:

```
...


def enter_pressed(event):
    text_field.config(state=NORMAL)

    name = input_name2.get()
    # Добавляем имя пользователя + двоеточие, для него указываем тег user_name
    text_field.insert(END, name + ":" + "\n", "user_name")
    
    input_get = input_field.get()
    text_field.insert(END, input_get + "\n")

    text_field.config(state=DISABLED)
    input_user.set('')


text_field = Text(root, width=57, height=47, bg='#F5F5F5')
text_field.pack_propagate(False)
input_field.bind('<Return>', enter_pressed)
text_field.pack(anchor=E, side=RIGHT)
text_field.config(state=DISABLED)

# Для текста с тегом "user_name" указываем синий цвет текста
text_field.tag_configure('user_name', foreground="blue")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,  уже не знал что делать